# Selenium WebDriver stops without printing XPath

Tags: python, selenium, mozilla, geckodriver

I am trying to print the XPath data in the console. But the process stops after loading the first page even without no errors.

This is my code:

```
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=10')
while True:
    try:
        elm = browser.find_element_by_link_text("next")
        elm.click()
        labels = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/h3/a')
        for label in labels:
            print label.text
    except:
        break
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess u are getting exception after 1st run so it's jumping into except and breaking your loop. Try without exception handling

Comment: yeah tried it, but no change

Comment: The method `find_element_by_xpath` returns a single element or `None`. It does not return a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why are not getting any errors is because you are catching them and then just using ***break***.

You also had an issue with your ***XPATH*** to the question labels. I included a scroll to the `next` link in case you are receiving the cookies notification at the bottom like I was. Here is a working example:

> NOTE: This was testing in Python 3 using current Chrome build *67* and
>   chromedriver *2.40*

```
import traceback
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=10')
while True:
    try:
        elm = browser.find_element_by_link_text("next")
        browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm)
        elm.click()
        labels = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@class="question-hyperlink"]')
        for label in labels:
            print(label.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("only catching this exception now when you run out of the next elements, other exceptions will raise")
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        break
```

Comment: Am getting error:except
    NoSuchElementException as e:
    NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined

Comment: You have to import it, try the updated code with the import.